# Reorder tableview cells in Core Data in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, draggable

I'm new to iOS programming, especially when it comes to Core Data. I have an app with To-Do list, where I use TableView inside ViewController. I needed to reorder tableview cells with drag, but at the same time without editing mode, so I've chosen this library:
https://github.com/sivu22/LongPressReorder
I need to save the position of reordered table view cells and I've tried literally every solution related to Swift both on StackOverflow and on the Internet in general.
By this moment I have an attribute named "orderPosition" inside an Entity named "Inbox":

[image: d]

From the library above I've added 2 functions (see below) to my ViewController

```
override func positionChanged(currentIndex: IndexPath, newIndex: IndexPath) {
        // currentIndex and newIndex rows are swapped, implement accordingly

    }

    override func reorderFinished(initialIndex: IndexPath, finalIndex: IndexPath) {
        // Gesture is finished and cell is back inside the table at finalIndex position

    }
```

I add code inside the second func, as it is called after gesture is finished.

Here is the code I used in my ViewController Extension:

```
override func positionChanged(currentIndex: IndexPath, newIndex: IndexPath) {
        // currentIndex and newIndex rows are swapped, implement accordingly

    }

    override func reorderFinished(initialIndex: IndexPath, finalIndex: IndexPath) {
        // Gesture is finished and cell is back inside the table at finalIndex position
        self.loadSaveData()

        let task = tasks[initialIndex.row]
        tasks.remove(at: initialIndex.row)
        tasks.insert(task, at: finalIndex.row)

        var i = 0
        for task in tasks {
            i += 1
            task.setValue(i, forKey: "orderPosition")
        }

        do {
            try self.manageObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error While Deleting Note: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Where:

```
func loadSaveData()  {

        let inboxRequest: NSFetchRequest<Inbox> = Inbox.fetchRequest()
        inboxRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "orderPosition", ascending: true)]
        do{
            inboxArray = try manageObjectContext.fetch(inboxRequest)
            self.tableView1.reloadData()
        }catch
        {
            print("Could not load save data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

This is declaration of inboxArray, manageObjectContext and tasks:

```
var tasks: [NSManagedObject] = []
var inboxArray = [Inbox]()
var manageObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
```

Comment: The attributes that I really use in my "Inbox" entity are: "orderPosition" and "task". The other ones are like "orderPosition", but with different name and they will be deleted.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What have you tried so far? You need to post some code so we know how to help

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I've posted my code